# What is the upgrade path for taking Ubuntu 6.06 LTS Server to Ubuntu 8.10 Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

My development team uses a Ubuntu 6.06 LTS Server VMware image as our development environment.  It has our development stack on it.  I would like to upgrade that to Ubuntu 8.10 Desktop (Note: Desktop, not Server) . . . while not breaking any of the development stack in the original image.  The development stack uses apt-get packages in the 6.06 distro.

Answer (score 6):

- [Perform a network upgrade to the next LTS release (8.04) first](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading-8.04#head-e059d5452a24b50d09c64df48058ef2d834eb197-2)
- [Then upgrade to 8.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading#Network%20Upgrade%20for%20Ubuntu%20Servers%20(Recommended))
- Now you have an 8.10 server. To install the desktop, just do

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

And you're good to go! You might have a small number of things going awry in the upgrade - one thing that happened to me going to 8.04 was that trac was configured differently, but happiness was just a Google search away.

Comment: After doing the network upgrade to 8.04 Server LTS, my network connections do not work.  eth0 exists.  But, it does not have an IP addess.  I think this could be a solutions.  But, there is something breaking my network connectivity.

Comment: Double check /etc/network/interfaces and try /etc/init.d/networking restart after making any changes.

Comment: yep.  checked and restarted.  Still no good.  Have Googled and tried a lot of different solutions.  Not sure what to do.  I am going to try the network upgrade again.  There may have been something I chose during the install process that was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A direct upgrade from 6.06 to 8.10 is not supported.  An upgrade from 6.06 to 8.04 should work, and an upgrade from 8.04 to 8.10 should work.  Since you are using VMs I would strongly recommend that you take a snapshot before you attempt the upgrade.

Take time to check google, ubuntu forums, and ubuntu wiki for the specific packages you use. for upgrade issues before attempting this.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to install another kernel, because Ubuntu Server comes with a kernel configured for servers, not desktops. You can do this with, for example, `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic`